# Implement persistent counter

Tags: perl

I want to create a sort of counter that is persistent but I don't want to use the database for that (no other reason but I prefer to avoid creating a table for just having a counter which I won't need in a few months anyway).
So my problem is that I want to count how many times I do something in a function but when
the script re-runs I want to increment the existing count.
I thought to create a file and just add the count to the file and update the file but I thought perhaps
there is an abstraction ready to use for something like this.

Comment: Maybe try https://metacpan.org/pod/Storable but using `open()` is the simpler solution I think

Comment: Check http://perldoc.perl.org/AnyDBM_File.html

Comment: Both solutions seems overkill for a simple counter, no ?

Comment: @sputnick true, if OP wants only one counter.

Comment: @Сухой27:Yes just a counter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not using counter in concurrent environment,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub increment {
  my ($file) = @_;
  open my $fh, "+>>", $file or die $!;

  seek($fh, 0, 0);
  my $count = <$fh> // 0;
  seek($fh, 0, 0);
  truncate($fh, 0);

  print $fh ++$count;      
  close $fh or die $!;

  return $count;
}

my $current_count = increment("/tmp/counter");
```

Comment: It is not concurrent but I would need to check what the number is as well as increment it

Comment: I tried it. It does not work. I see in the file: "1" and in the second call "12" in the next call "1213" etc